# How to display all database which are related to mongodb using perl script

Tags: mongodb, perl

Can anyone help me to display all the MongoDB databases using a Perl script?

I connected to MongoDB and I'm stuck after this.

My code is the following:

```perl
use MongoDB; 
use MongoDB::OID;
use Data::Dumper; 

use strict;
use warnings;

use lib '.';
use Exporter qw(import);

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(teller);

my $client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new(
    host => 'localhost',
    port => 27020
);
my $db_list = listDatabases();

foreach my $n ( $#db_list ) {
    say $db_list[$n];
}
```

But I get the error:

```
Global symbol "@db_list" requires explicit package name
```

Comment: You seem to have written a Frankenstein's monster of a program. It seems to be both a program and a module at the same time. It tries to export `teller`, which it doesn't define, but also has a `for` loop that attempts to iterate of the (last index of) array `@db_list`, which isn't declared or defined. You also call `listDatabases`, which isn't defined either. You must say *exactly* what it is that you're trying to do here, as *"all the MongoDB databases"* doesn't mean much

Answer (score 2):

There's rather a lot wrong with these two lines.

```
my $db_list = listDatabases();
foreach my $n ($#db_list) { say $db_list[$n]; }
```

Your error is caused by confusion between array and scalar variables with the same name.

`my $db_list` declares a scalar variable. But `$#db_list` refers to an array called `@db_list`. You probably meant `$#{$db_List}`. But even that doesn't do what you want as `foreach my $n ($#{$db_list})` iterates across a list containing a single item. I think you probably wanted:

```
foreach my $n (0 .. $#{$db_list})
```

There's a little guesswork involved here as I don't know how your `listDatabases()` subroutine works. You act like it returns an array reference, but it's possible that it returns an array, in which your code should be:

```
# Note: array, not scalar
my @db_list = listDatabases();
foreach my $n (0 .. $#db_list) { say $db_list[$n]; }
```

Without knowing more about `listDatabases()` it's impossible to be sure.

I'll note that [MongoDB::MongoClient](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::MongoClient) has a method called `database_names()`. You could use that like this:

```
my @db_list = $client->database_names;
foreach my $n (0 .. $#db_list) { say $db_list[$n]; }
```

Comment: your suggestion helps me a lot.. Thank u so much

Comment: @Madhu: If my suggestions are useful, please consider upvoting or accepting my answer.